# Pandas iloc() to identify specific columns from headers row?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a list of the column headers excluding the initial columns. I am trying to use Pandas' iloc function for this and I feel I am halfway there.

```
column_dates = list(pronto.iloc[[0][2:]])
print(column_dates)
```

Right now, this is returning

```
['Unwanted Variable 1', 'Unwanted Variable 2', 'January 2018', 'February 2018', 'March 2018', 'April 2018', 'May 2018', 'June 2018', 'July 2018', 'August 2018', 'September 2018', 'October 2018', 'November 2018', 'December 2018', 'January 2019', 'February 2019', 'March 2019', 'April 2019', 'May 2019', 'June 2019', 'July 2019', 'August 2019', 'September 2019', 'October 2019', 'November 2019']
```

How do I specify within iloc that I want the first row (column headers) and then columns 2(3rd column really) onward? I need the columns to be open ended as the width of the data frame can vary depending on the amount of months,

Essentially I want this back,

```
['January 2018', 'February 2018', 'March 2018', 'April 2018', 'May 2018', 'June 2018', 'July 2018', 'August 2018', 'September 2018', 'October 2018', 'November 2018', 'December 2018', 'January 2019', 'February 2019', 'March 2019', 'April 2019', 'May 2019', 'June 2019', 'July 2019', 'August 2019', 'September 2019', 'October 2019', 'November 2019']
```

Comment: `df.columns[start_no:]`?

Comment: You're a genius! This is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the names of the columns have been properly parsed, then you want

```
pronto.columns[2:]
```

if the names of your columns are appearing in your dataframe as the first row (which they shouldn't), this should work

```
pronto.iloc[0, 2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The output from `column_dates` is a vector and not a `DataFrame`. You can simply subset without using `iloc` e.g.

```
df = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

suppose you want to select the third element in the list and onwards, just use, (remember Python index starts at 0)

```
df[2:] 

[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Hopefully this helps